# Mocking a WebClient post method when there's a request body, fails in maven build

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, integration-testing, webclient

I am mocking a WebClient object when doing a post call with a body. I'm just using Mockito not mockwebserver.

This is the method I'm testing:

```
public class RestClient{

public void send(){
    webclient
.post()
.contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
.headers(getHeaders())
.syncBody(requestObj)
.retrieve()
.bodyToMono(Void.class)
.block();
}
}
```

And this is the test class code which works fine for the above post call.

```
@Mock
WebClient webClient;

@Mock
WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec requestBodyUriSpec;

@Mock
WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec requestHeadersSpec;

@Mock
WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestBodySpec;

@Mock
WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec;

@InjectMocks
RestClient restClient;
```

mocking the post call in a method :

```
    when(webClient.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);
    when(requestBodyUriSpec.contentType(any())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
    when(requestBodySpec.headers(any()).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
    when(requestBodySpec.syncBody(any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpec);
    when(requestHeadersSpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);
    when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(Void.class)
            .thenReturn(Mono.empty());

    
    Mockito.verify(webClient,atLeast(1)).post();
```

Again the integration test method is passed if i run the integration test class individually.

But on running the maven build, it fails the same test method with an exception :

Maven build logs:

```
Time elapsed : 1.136  <<< FAILURE!
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.WantedButNotInvoked:

webClient bean.post();
at ....
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Any ideas what's wrong there?

Comment: Are you on junit 4 or 5 (aka jupiter), 
Do you have a `@Before`/ `@BeforeEach` method, and is it initialising the Mocks properly.
It looks to me like there is likely some issue with interaction between different Test classes interferring with each other.

Comment: You are not calling `restClient.send()` in your test, are you?

Comment: @lesiak, the OP mentions that the tests pass when run in isolation, so I guess the `send` method must get called somwhere in the chain (why I mention interactions with other mocks).

Comment: My Springboot API is on junit5. @Before method is present in the test class but it is not initialising any of the mocks mentioned above in the code.

Comment: Above mocks are already annotated with @Mock, then what do we need to initialize in @Before?